# "WHERE" is not working in mySQL statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

mySQL statement here tries to print total invoice amount by the year.

```
> select YEAR(I.INV_DATE), SUM(LINE_UNITS * LINE_PRICE) as total    from
> INVOICE I, LINE L     where I.INV_NUMBER = L.INV_NUMBER   group by 1
```

but if I add like (print only those greater than 500 for the year)

```
> select YEAR(I.INV_DATE), SUM(LINE_UNITS * LINE_PRICE) as total    from
> INVOICE I, LINE L     where I.INV_NUMBER = L.INV_NUMBER   group by 1
>         where total > 500
```

gives me error message : error in syntax

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks!!

Comment: what do you mean by group by 1

Comment: it means group by the first select statement which is the year

Comment: then you need to use having instead of where

Comment: because when you want conditions on function then use having instead of where

Answer (score 1):

use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

```
SELECT....
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING SUM(LINE_UNITS * LINE_PRICE) > 500
```

or you can wrap it in a subquery like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  YEAR(I.INV_DATE), SUM(LINE_UNITS * LINE_PRICE) as total
    FROM    INVOICE I, LINE L
    WHERE   I.INV_NUMBER = L.INV_NUMBER   
    GROUP   BY 1
) a
WHERE total > 500
```

Comment: in standard sql, never use the alias in the `HAVING` clause. Although it is permitted to work on Mysql only.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT YEAR(I.INV_DATE), SUM(LINE_UNITS * LINE_PRICE) as total 
FROM INVOICE I, LINE L     
WHERE  I.INV_NUMBER = L.INV_NUMBER   
GROUP BY 1
HAVING total > 500
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html
You need to use `HAVING` with `GROUP BY`